# fglrx support for ATI FirePro 2460 with 4 heads

Tags: fglrx

I am running 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux with the FirePro 2460. This is a single GPU with 4 heads. I can get 3 monitors working fine each running under a different xserver DISPLAY name, :0.0, :0.1, :0.2. When I add the fourth monitor, I end up with the following error in Xorg.0.log

> [4.063] (EE) fglrx(3): Display Infrastructure Failed Due to Hardware Limitation
>   [4.063] (EE) fglrx(3): PreInit failed

Is this the correct place to pose this question? I have attached xorg.conf and Xorg.0.log if anyone can direct me to an answer or the correct place to ask the question.

Thanks,
Donald Kayser

```
==========================  xorg.conf =============================================


Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
            Screen         "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
        Screen         "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
        Screen         "Screen3" RightOf "Screen2"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor-0"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Device-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Device-1"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
        Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Device-2"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
        Screen      2 
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Device-3"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
        Screen      3
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Default Screen"
DefaultDepth     24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Device-0"
        Monitor    "Monitor-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen1"
        Device     "Device-1"
        Monitor    "Monitor-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
    Depth     24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen2"
        Device     "Device-2"
        Monitor    "Monitor-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen3"
        Device     "Device-3"
        Monitor    "Monitor-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection  
 EndSection
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else finds this post, I have an answer from AMD.

"You cannot connect 4 different DVI monitors. You should only connect them through the Display Port. All Display Port monitors can share a single clock whereas each DVI monitor needs its own clock, so the number of possible DVI/HDMI connections is limited."

FYI. I was able to get two pairs of identical monitors to work. Each at its own resolution.